# ¿Como puedo restringir la orientación de mi app en ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

¿Como puedo restringir la orientación de mi aplicación a que solo se pueda ver en vertical usando **ionic 2**?

En la pagina oficial de ionic, busque Orientation y en los resultados de busqueda salio un plugin nativo de ionic que se llama **Screen Orientation.** dice como installarlo en mi aplicacion por medio de la linea de comando, pero no me dejo installar,

**la instrucion fue la siguiente:**

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation`.

**El resultado fue:** 
`cordova is not a valid task`

Comment: Has de mostrar lo que has intentado y si no has intentado nada, has de investigar primero y probar a implementar. Explicarnos qué errores te ha generado o problemas surgidos. Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Un saludo

Comment: en la pagina oficial de ionic, busque Orientation y en los resultados de busqueda salio un plugin nativo de ionic que se llama Screen Orientation.
dice como installarlo en mi aplicacion por medio de la linea de comando, pero no me dejo installar, la instrucion fue la siguiente: ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation. El resultado fue: cordova is not a valid task

Comment: Añade eso a la pregunta con el boton de [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A esa instrucción le sobra el `ionic`. Para que funcione sería tan solo:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

Con la que le estás diciendo a Cordova (`cordova`) que instale (`add`) el `plugin` llamado `cordova-plugin-screen-orientation`. Puedes encontrar más información [página web del plugin en npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation).

Comment: C:\Users\Usuario\Dropbox\AllMarketIonic\AllMarket>cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" to config.xml
Adding cordova-plugin-screen-orientation to package.json

Comment: Entonces... ¿funcionó?

Comment: si y no, una de las instruciones que habia dado antes habia instalado el plugin pero como que incompleto o algo asi, entonces la borre y lo volvi a installa y ahora creo que si esta funcionando, por que no lanza ningun error, solo que no tengo en este momento un dispositivo para probar, pero igual muchas gracias

Comment: tengo otro problema y no se si sea por que lo esto probando en un navegador de mi portátil, pero pasa lo siguiente:uso  console.log(this.screenOrientation.type); y esto me lanza por consola el tipo de orientación correctamente, pero uso this.screenOrientation.lock("landscape-primary"); y me lanza este error:  Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): NotSupportedError: screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device.

Comment: Creo que eso puede ser porque lo estás probando en el navegador, y que no debería fallarte en un dispositivo/emulador.